# Unrecognized option: -MaxMetaspaceSize=256m

Tags: java, oracle, jvm

While ordinary run under IDEA I've got:

> /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java ...
>
> Unrecognized option: -MaxMetaspaceSize=256m
> Error: Could not create
> the Java Virtual Machine.
> Error: A fatal exception has occurred.
> Program will exit.
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Why can't I add the -MaxMetaspaceSize=256m JVM property?

---

Additional info:

echo $JAVA_HOME

> /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/lib

sudo update-alternatives --config java

> There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing
> /usr/bin/java).
>
> Selection    Path                                     Priority
>
> ---
>
> - 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java   9         auto mode
>   1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java   8   manual mode

The same for javac & javaws, project settings, module, default settings are using jre8 & javac8.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct name of the parameter is `-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize`.

Answer (score 1):

From java 8, PermSize and MaxPermSize JVM arguments are ignored and replaced by MetaspaceSize and MaxMetaspaceSize.

The Maximum metaspace size can be set using the -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize flag,and the default is unlimited,which means that only your system memory is the limit and for PermSize use -XX:MetaspaceSize.