# How to configure java home on flink job on yarn

Tags: apache-flink

I submit a job to the hadoop cluster on the flink client, do I need to configure the java home path in flink conf?

If you need to configure，

Should I configure the java home of the client machine or the java home of the hadoop cluster？

When I did not configure java home, I submitted the job error as follows

```
LogType:jobmanager.err
Log Upload Time:Fri Jan 22 17:27:25 -0800 2021
LogLength:160
Log Contents:
Unrecognized VM option 'MaxMetaspaceSize=268435456'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Answer (score 2):

According the output you posted, you problem is not java_path (yet!)
The line

> Unrecognized VM option 'MaxMetaspaceSize=268435456'

You need to remove MaxMetaspaceSize from configuration or replace it with: -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize

you can get help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32008475/unrecognized-option-maxmetaspacesize-256m) issue.

Comment: Thanks!
         
I tried to add the following parameters to the flink run command

```-yD env.java.opts="-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=268435456" ```

But it still prints the above error

Comment: @JacobCao you need to replace it with MaxMetaspaceSize.

Comment: @JacobCao - Can you please let know how did you solve this? I'm facing the same issue with Flink 1.14.2 and have tried with Java 8/11 as well. Passing through the parameters also didn't help.

Comment: @user3497321 After testing, I found that the path of Java home must be specified in the Flink configuration file, and this path must be consistent with the Java home path of the Hadoop cluster, thanks!